# Why I am getting error while using get method in Flask python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-restful

I am trying to get data from url by using get method in flask and python but getting

```
192.168.0.128 - - [22/Feb/2019 16:40:18] "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.
192.168.0.128 - - [22/Feb/2019 16:51:39] "GET /autocomplete?input=%27mumbai%27 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

url: `http://192.168.0.128:5000/autocomplete?input=%27mumbai%27`

Script:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
#cors = CORS(app)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/foo": {"origins": "http://localhost:port"}})

app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/autocomplete', methods=['GET']) 
@cross_origin(origin='localhost',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
def AutoComplete():

    data = request.args.get('input')
    print (data)

    #http://192.168.0.128:5000/autocomplete=?input=mumbai

    spellchecker = SpellChecker()
    tokens = spellchecker.correct_phrase(data)
    result = AutoCompleter().guess_exercises(tokens)

    return result[:10]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.0.128', port=5000)
```

Comment: Not a flask user so it might not be the problem, but you send a request to `/autocomplete/` (trailing slash) while map your controller to `'/autocomplete'` (no trailing slash). Those are NOT the same url.

Comment: try to convert the result[:10] to json before return it, the API can't give u back whatever u want.... import jsonify and then return jsonify(result[:10])

Answer (score 1):

There is an error sent back to you. That error is error [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).

From Wikipedia:
*emphasized The HTTP 404, 404 Not Found, and 404 error message is a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) standard response code, in computer network communications, to indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.*

Try changing the request from `/autocomplete/` to `/autocomplete`

Comment: The issue now is going to be a bug in your code.
Please check out the comments from the original question.